# Eclipse Crashing in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 14.10, 15.04, eclipse

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.10 and my eclipse Luna keep crashing abruptly. Same was happening in Ubuntu14.10. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

It just shuts down anytime. Not found any consistent behaviour. It happens try to write something, or sometimes when opening some file and sometimes it keeps working for an hour without creating any problem.

also tried one solution of adding **-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla** in eclipse.ini file but no solution.

Please suggest some solution. This is very - 2 irritating. . I am unable to do any work

Adding Terminal output, with last fail. This time it shut down when I was trying to install some plugin. Also, one more thing that I noticed is many times it just freezes the whole system and everything keyboard,mouse stops working and I have to force shut it down.

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/incredible/दस्तावेज़/Eclipse Workspacw/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.5.0.20140606-0033.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
Unable to load cache.
eclipse: ../../../../src/cairo-pattern.c:3714: _cairo_pattern_get_extents: Assertion `status == CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Start eclipse in a terminal and post the messages.

Comment: Several follow-up question:
 - Have you tried switching between java versions? If you have another versions installed, you can switch by `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
 - Have you considered that using Hindi symbols (/home/incredible/*दस्तावेज़*/...) in your path would be the reason for crashing?

Comment: didn't noticed earlier. . but I can try today.

Comment: I tried to change workspace, but It didn't work. Eclipse again freezed whole system and I had to do force shutdown

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, I think the first option is the better choice:

- Reinstall Eclipse

---

- Remove M2Eclipse and install the plugin again

Open the your eclipse installation folder, in your case `~/eclipse` remove the following:

```
rm -r ~/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.*
rm -r ~/eclipse/features/org.eclipse.m2e.*
```

Restart Eclipse and install M2Eclipse again:

Start Eclipse and install the plugin [M2Eclipse](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases) again.

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
```

Comment: I don't have this folder in my home directory

Comment: Where is your eclipse installed? In `/opt/eclipse`?

Comment: I downloaded Eclipse.tar and extracted in my home directory

Comment: You have installed eclipse in `~/eclipse` right?

Comment: yes! I have plugin Directory ~/eclipse/plugins. I had deleted all the m2e related folders and jars from the plugins directory. When I started Eclipse from terminal, it didn't show me that exception. But it still hanged complete system after sometime